# How to create custom fields at project level in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

Currently, I'm trying to create some custom fields, but I don't want to repeat them in all the tasks, I want to use the option of custom fields by project but the option is disabled. I want to know how to enable it and use it inside my project.

The highlighted option is disabled.

[image: Custom Fields dialog - Project radio button disabled]

Comment: I don't have an option like that (is "proyecto" = "draft" in English?!?) - what version of Project are you using?

Comment: I´'m using Project 2013

Comment: apparently, that option is only enabled when MS Project is connected to Project Server.
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms447495(v=office.14).aspx#pj14_EnterpriseCF_Enterprise)

Comment: I am getting a strange behavior of this option, I have two system one is a Desktopwith Win 7 and MPP 2010 which is provided by client and can be used at client location only and another one is Laptop (provided by my organization for WFH) it too have Win 7 and MPP 2010 but my Desktop have this option not my Laptop.

Comment: @Pipe2290 is correct.  The abilty to create Project level fields is only available when running Project Professional connected to Project Server.  So are both your laptop and desktop project professional?  Are both connected either to Project Server or Project Online?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN: Local and Enterprise Custom Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms447495(v=office.12).aspx#pj12_EnterpriseCF_LocalAndEnterprise)

> **Local Custom Fields**
>
> (...)
>
> You can assign **local custom fields to resources and tasks, but not
>   to projects**. In practice, if you use interim plans you should not
>   use the task Start1-10 or Finish1-10 custom fields because Project
>   uses those fields to store dates for interim baseline plans.
>
> (...)
>
> **Enterprise Custom Fields**
>
> (...)
>
> Enterprise custom fields can be assigned to **projects**, resources,
>   and tasks in Project Server.
>
> (...)